# "Andrew looked at him in the mirror": can "him" refer to Andrew?

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

> (1) Andrew looked at **him** in the mirror. 
>   (2) Andrew looked at **himself** in the mirror.

Does (1) include (2)’s possibility? Or does *him* in (1) only refer to someone other than Andrew?

Comment: Your second interpretation is correct; in this context "*him*" can only apply to a non-Andrew person; if Andrew is looking at Andrew the he is looking at *himself*.

Comment: without 'himself' he's definitely looking at someone else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two are separate from one another:

In [1], 'him' must mean someone else, as it is not a reflexive pronoun (that is, a pronoun ending in 'self'). Andrew is thus looking at another person.

In [2], 'himself' is a reflexive pronoun, so Andrew is looking at Andrew('s reflection).